# How to discourage clang-format to break after = signs?

Tags: c++, clang-format

I'm using clang-format with a fairly minimal configuration file, and I'm not very familiar with the options. For the sake of the question, consider this piece of unformatted code:

```
int msgResult = ShowMBox(R_MESSAGE, msgText, MB_OK_ENABLE | MB_CANCEL_ENABLE, MB_STYLE_ERROR);
```

When I run clang-format on this snippet, I get

```
int msgResult
    = ShowMBox(R_MESSAGE, msgText, MB_OK_ENABLE | MB_CANCEL_ENABLE, MB_STYLE_ERROR);
```

But I'd prefer

```
int msgResult = ShowMBox(R_MESSAGE, msgText, MB_OK_ENABLE | MB_CANCEL_ENABLE, 
                         MB_STYLE_ERROR);
```

Is there a way to enforce not breaking after `=`, or at least prefer not to?

Comment: what formatting options have you tried?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I tried BinPackArguments and BinPackParameters but it's not entirely what I needed. Also, sometimes it does format the way I posted, but I couldn't discover the exact conditions.

Comment: I'm afraid this behavior is not configurable.  Try uncrustify ( https://github.com/bengardner/uncrustify ), it has much more options.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want these two style options:

```
BinPackArguments: true
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
```

Without `BinPackArguments`, clang-format will try to either put all function arguments on one line, or if it can't will put one function argument per line. Most of the pre-defined styles already set `BinPackArguments` to `true`, but the `Mozilla` style does not.

Without `AlignAfterOpenBracket` set to `Align`, clang-format will sometimes prefer to put all arguments on the second line, rather than just a single argument that doesn't line up with the other arguments. Most of the pre-defined styles already set `AlignAfterOpenBracket` to `Align`, but the `WebKit` style does not.

See the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) for more details about these settings.

My testing was done with clang-format 6.0.0. Perhaps you had an earlier version that didn't support all this.